# Get active session count from Spring Session Redis

Tags: redis, spring-session

I need to know the number of active sessions in a Spring Cloud based application. It has multiple microservices, and Session information is shared using Redis (@EnableRedisHttpSession).

What would be valuable data to represent the number of *active* sessions? You'd think it is just the number of keys (Redis isn't used for anything else), but the keys count is a lot more - around 200, while there is maybe 20 active sessions in my test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the keys that match the *spring:session:sessions:[session_id_uuid]* pattern, where *[session_id_uuid]* is the Spring Session generated id of a session.

This is assuming you're not using a custom key namespace (`EnableRedisHttpSession#redisNamespace`). If you do, you need to also take that into consideration so the pattern becomes *spring:session:[namespace]:sessions:[session_id_uuid]*

Comment: Yes, that was my original plan that returned 200 keys. Seems like there was some old stale data in Redis that never got flushed.

Comment: Just as a followup - the 200 entries were actually due to some testing tool that was pinging the production server every few minutes. Seems like just displaying the login page creates an initial session in redis. I moved the testing tool to ping site.com/health instead.